# How to populate a master sheet for multiple other sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a workbook that had 7 different sheets,

Each sheet has a column that is labeled Companies. How would I go about setting up a formula that would add the companies names to master sheet as they are being types in each of the other sheets.

For Example, the master sheet will start out blank... and then I would type in sheet 1 companies a, b, c, and d. I would like those companies to automatically appear in the master sheet. But if i type in sheet 2 e,f,g, and b I would only want " a,b,c,d,e,f,g" in the master sheet because I dont want the same company to appear twice in the master sheet's company column. My main goal is for the master sheets company column to be automatically filled from the other sheets when a company is entered into them, but if the same company is entered on two or more of those sheets I would only like it to appear once on the master sheet.

Thank you for any help, please let me know if there are any questions.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e

Comment: This function is only suit for part of Office 365 version,

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't think of an simple formula that would do this for you. Assuming this is just a simple template and won't be having frequent additions I would copy the companies over to the master sheet.

Next highlight light the area you just populated then under the Data tab in Excel removed duplicates.